# Сколько у вас комнат?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

Which one of these two is correct?

(1) "У меня есть пять комнат."

OR

(2) "У меня есть пять комнаты"

I also noticed that if using номер. I get a slightly different answer:

Сколько у вас номер?
"У меня есть пять номеров."

Why does the номер switch over to -OB?

Comment: What do you mean by "номер"? Will you say that in English?

Comment: "номер" I have been told is a hotel room. When I used "номер" in the speech machine I got: "У меня есть пять номеров." The -OB, is that genitive pluralis that kicks in, in this case?

Comment: The question should be "сколько у вас номеров?"

Comment: @Ana, I guess it was supposed to be "Сколько у вас комнат *в номере*?" – "У меня в номере пять комнат" (the verb "*есть*" is normally dropped in Russian and "номер" *contains* one or more rooms, just like a *flat* does)

Comment: У меня есть пять комнат implies that you probably have five rooms in different apartments (yes, sometimes apartments are owned on per-room basis).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rules are pretty well known and hard-set:

- any number ending on "**один**" (like "сто тридцать тысяч двести пятьдесят ***один***") requires the noun to be **singular** in *nominative case*.
- any number ending on "**два**", "**три**" или "**четыре**" requires the noun to be *singular* in *genitive case*.
- any other number (including "teens") requires the noun to be *plural* in *genitive case*.

According to that rule,

> У меня есть пять ***ко́мнат***.

"**Ко́мнат**" – genitive of "**ко́мнаты**", which is plural of "**ко́мната**".

and

> У меня есть пять ***номеро́в***.

"**Номеро́в**" – genitive of "**номера́**", which is plural of "**но́мер**".

Answer (score 2):

***У меня пять комнат*** или ***В моём номере пять комнат*** (если речь идёт о номере в отеле). Глагол ***есть*** в этих конструкциях не нужен.